# Ignorar acentos na busca "filtro" Angular

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, input

Na (imagem 1) preciso criar uma categoria, só que eu não posso criar uma que já existe (imagem 2). Porém como posso fazer para ignorar os acentos? Porque na (imagem 3) já é possivel criar uma categoria com o mesmo nome porém sem os acentos e não é este o comportamento na qual espero. Segue código abaixo. Usei toLocaleLowerCase() então ele diferencia tranquilo letras maiusculas das minusculas.

[Imagem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mlv1.png)

[Imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtBAy.png)

[Imagem 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy2du.png)

TS

```
 public validateCategoryName(): void {
    if (!this.parent?.subcategories && !this.parent?.childrens) {
        console.log('this.parent.sub', this.parent?.subcategories)
        let categorie: CategoryItem = this.allCategories.find((categories) => categories?.description.toLocaleLowerCase() && categories?.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === this.categoryName.toLocaleLowerCase());
        if (categorie) {
            console.log(categorie)
            this.existingCategoriesError = true;
        } else {
            this.existingCategoriesError = false;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="full-width-input">
    <label>{{ 'flexibleCharacteristics.dialogForm.name' | translate }}</label>
    <input matInput class="form-input" [(ngModel)]="categoryName" (input)="validateCategoryName()"
        [placeholder]="'flexibleCharacteristics.dialogForm.placeholder.name-category' | translate">
        <p class="not-match" *ngIf="!validateSubCategoryName()">
            {{ '"' +  categoryName + '" ' + ('flexibleCharacteristics.dialogForm.subCategoryExists' | translate) + ' "' + parent?.name + '".' }}
        </p>
        <p class="not-match" *ngIf="existingCategoriesError">
            {{ 'flexibleCharacteristics.dialogForm.categoryExists' | translate }}
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma.

Criei um arquivo chamado **remove-accents.validator.ts**

```
  /**
 * Ignore accents when input validation is needed.
 */

export function removeAccents(text: string): string {
    text = text?.toLowerCase();                                                         
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/[\xE0-\xE6]/g), 'a');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/[\xE8-\xEB]/g), 'e');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/[\xEC-\xEF]/g), 'i');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/[\xF2-\xF6]/g), 'o');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/[\xF9-\xFC]/g), 'u');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/\xE7/g), 'c');
    text = text?.replace(new RegExp(/\xF1/g), 'n');
    return text;  
}
```

E coloquei dentro do método no TS.

```
 public validateCategoryName(): void {
    if (!this.parent?.subcategories && !this.parent?.childrens) {
        let categorie: CategoryItem = this.allCategories.find((categories) => removeAccents(categories?.description.toLocaleLowerCase()) && removeAccents(categories?.name.toLocaleLowerCase()) === removeAccents(this.categoryName.toLocaleLowerCase()));
        if (categorie) {
            this.existingCategoriesError = true;
        } else {
            this.existingCategoriesError = false;
        }
    }
}
```